# JavaScript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined on line 13

Tags: javascript

this is my first CS project and the goal is to write a translator in JS. When I run my code it works but I get the error that it is undefined on the line after the for loop.

```
sentence_to_translate = "I am a proud computer science student"
pig= "ay "

words = sentence_to_translate.split(' ')

for (var i = 0; i < sentence_to_translate.length ; i++) {
    document.write((words[i].substring(i-i+1)+ words[i].substring(i-i,1) + pig))
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: you should loop through `words` instead of sentence_to_translate, `words` is array of words from sentence_to_translate

Comment: what you want to achive. plz post your expected output? `Iay maay aay roudpay omputercay ciencesay tudentsay`

Comment: Also in your `.substring` you have a `i-i` operation, which will always return 0, so you might want to correct that according to your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop condition to `i < words.length` as your indexes are starting from 0 so if array length is 5, 5th element will be available on 4th index